# jq automatically click onclick event

Tags: jquery

Support IE8 / 9/10 JQ automatically click a button onclick, such as $ (". BtnNormal"). Trigger ("click"), is the only supported ie11, I need to support IE8 / 9/10/11 automatically click onclick event buttons

Answer (score 0):

Haha, originally I was funny, drill a dead end, as one first with jq jq but never thought that encapsulates js, js using native to solve the problem, document.getElementById ("ct116") click ().;